# sharepoint date column calculation

Tags: calculated-column, date-time

This is my first day using SharePoint and I was lost in trying to figure out how or if it can be done, custom column calculations, and if code is allowed in SharePoint?  I am using SharePoint 2010.  I had someone else create my own site and I have been in the entire thing all day and its exciting!  I figured I would be doing a lot on my own so I created a custom list.  I am wanting to do the following:

- ColumnA: Add the date you wish
- ColumnB: Would take the actual date and calculate how many days from the added date in Column A
- ColumnC: Will enter the closed date that will stop the counter in ColumnB.

In general I am creating a ticket system in SharePoint, but I dont know if it can be done or where to look for it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible without code. You will have to use so called *"Calculated Columns"*.

For your date calculations there are even special formulas such as this:

```
=DATE(YEAR(Column1)+Column2,MONTH(Column1),DAY(Column1))
```

which actually adds 3 years to the column

There are several examples here:

- [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071%28v=office.14%29)
- [Examples of common formulas](https://web.archive.org/web/20140328214131/http://office.microsoft.com:80/en-001/windows-sharepoint-services-help/examples-of-common-formulas-HA001160947.aspx)
- [Date Functions in Calculated Fields](https://web.archive.org/web/20151119051113/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2008/08/01/date-functions-in-calculated-fields.aspx)